# Inkscape stopped importing eps from command line

Tags: svg, inkscape, eps

Maybe it was with an earlier version of inkscape, but I used to be able to convert eps files to pdf files from the command line.

Eg. I'd type

```
 inkscape test.eps --export-pdf=test.pdf
```

And then my file would convert into a pdf, no problems. A few system updates and whatever else later, I now get the error.

> %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
>   ^
>
> ** (inkscape:3654): WARNING **: Specified document taylor.eps cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)

Any suggestions for how I might be able to get things up and working again?

```
 Inkscape --version
```

> Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 (Jan 22 2014)

```
 uname -a
```

> Linux MyMachineName 4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you have Ghostscript installed?  It is needed for EPS importing. https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#how-open-eps-files-windows

Comment: Also, Inkscape is now at version 0.92. Perhaps it's time to update? :)

Comment: Thanks @PaulLeBeau. I confirmed that ghostscript is indeed installed and updated to the newist stable version of inkscape. Still no luck.

Comment: I should add also, that I can open inkscape and manually import an eps file; I just can't import from command line.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work
`inkscape test.eps --export-pdf=test.pdf --without -gui`